# Reading large data from an inputstream some data missing at the end

Tags: java, inputstream

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
```

Hello,

I am using the httpUrlConnection to retrieve a json string from a webservice. Then I get the inputStream from the connection

```
jsonString = readJSONInputStream(mHttpUrlconnection.getInputStream());
```

I then use the following function to read the inputstream to get the JSON.

```
private String readJSONInputStream(final InputStream inputStream) {
    Reader reader = null;

    try {
         final int SIZE = 16024;

         char[] buffer = new char[SIZE];
         int bytesRead = 0;
         int read = 0;

         reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), SIZE);

         String line = "";
         String jsonString = "";

         while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonString += line;
         }

         /* Success */
         return jsonString;
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "UnsupportedEncodingexception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        /* close resources */
        try {
            reader.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, if the json is small say 600 bytes then everything is ok. But I have some JSON that is about 15000 bytes in size so I set the maximum size to 16024.

However, the JSON it only reads about about ~6511 and just cuts off.

If the JSON is small there is no problem < 1000 bytes. But for the larger JSON it only read about half of it.

I the data is there as I have tested this in a browswer using the http request plugin.

Am I doing anything wrong here. Anything I should check.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: How do you know how large the content should be in your program if you have never read it successfully?  Could there be an encoding issue at hand here?  I think you should post code which can be dumped into any IDE and run for testing.

Comment: Our webservice is where the json is. So our app will retrieve this json from our webservice. So we know what it contains.

Comment: I'm limited in my capacity to help because I don't even have the URL.  However, have you compared the JSON you _are_ able to download against what you cannot download?  Use an online diff checker and let us know what is missing.

Comment: I can't give the url as it our internal company's data. However, I have already compared what is on the webservice and what I have downloaded. Just ~half is always downloaded. The JSON is valid so there is nothing wrong with that. Our smaller JSON data is ok. I thought it had something to do with me reading from the inputstream.

Comment: Does _every_ JSON file have the same cutoff experience?  Or is this particular to this single file?

Comment: You have declared byte array and not using it effectively. Sample code: out = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);//// or you can hard code the filename
        // Read data into buffer and then write to the output file
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390793/cannot-download-file-from-url-in-java/33252453#33252453

Comment: I have other JSON's that work fine. But they are all less than 1000 bytes in length. I have just problem with this one, as it is about 15000 bytes in size.

Comment: Byte array code handles more than 3 MB file properly without any issues.

Comment: I have tested that code snippet and everything works fine and the json that gets written to the file contains the valid JSON. However, I need to write this to a String and return that.

Comment: Since when does `IndexOutOfBoundsException` mean 'unsupported encoding'? And where in your code is it even possible for `IndexOutOfBoundsException` to be thrown? When you get an exception, print *its* message, not some arbitrary sequence of characters of your own. And what exactly is `buffer` for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. Due to the logger not displaying all the information. Not really a problem afterall.